# Jenkins does not generate nunit reports

Tags: xml, jenkins, report, nunit

I have added a test project which uses nunit for unit testing. Unit tests pass, but the build fails, because Jenkins is not able to create xml report:

> Recording NUnit tests results FATAL: No NUnit test report files were
>   found. Configuration error? Build step 'Publish NUnit test result
>   report' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

Why is it trying to find files? Shouldn't it just create new or overwrite existing reports? I mean there are no reports generated before that, since it was a first build.

Answer (score 0):

The Nunit Plugin is for Publishing Reports generated using a build plugin of your build tool like maven/ant/gradle in Java/Android Ecosystem.

For example you can create junit reports using maven Cobertura Plugin/ JaCoCo etc for java projects in an junit style xml format in a folder location.

This plugin will provide UI reports/graphs on Jenkins based on xunit style reports generated by your build tool e.g. maven by parsing them. It will not generate the reports.

Comment: I also tried pointing it to a report that was generated by the nunit tool. It was still the same.

Comment: It seems its not able to locate the file can you try giving it an absolute path and a relative path from $WORKSPACE, normally its mentioned in the assist text ( Question Mark on the right ). I have a feeling this should be related to incorrect path , or the file generated is not of nunit style, try placing some sample nunit files searched from google there.. that might help

Answer (score 0):

Just try to run the Nunit console in your machine/server (where the Jenkins runs). Some times this error may occur if .NetFramework is missing